# Mikrotik PPTP VPN Setup

Tags: routing, vpn

I have attempted and followed many guides and am still having issues allowing traffic from my VPN to access devices on the LAN.

https://rbgeek.wordpress.com/2014/08/26/pptp-server-setup-on-mikrotik/
Is an example of one guide I have followed, and although I can connect, and ping from LAN > VPN I am unable to ping from VPN > LAN

I have the following setup:

Routerboard 750
WebFig v6.35.1 (stable)

`LAN 192.168.88.0/24`

`PPTP Pool 192.168.200.10-192.168.200.20`

`PPTP Server: Enabled`

`PPTP Profile created` using the PPTP IP Pool for both internal and external addresses

```
/ip pool
add name=dhcp ranges=192.168.88.100-192.168.88.254
add name=pptp-pool ranges=192.168.200.1-192.168.200.10<



# may/31/2016 23:02:50 by RouterOS 6.35.1
# software id = 8RIQ-2NZU
#
/ip firewall filter
add chain=input comment="default configuration" protocol=icmp
add chain=input comment="VPN PPTP ACCEPT" dst-port=1723 log=yes protocol=tcp
add chain=input comment="GRE ACCEPT" log=yes protocol=gre
add chain=input comment="default configuration" connection-state=established
add chain=input comment="default configuration" connection-state=related
add chain=input comment="allow l2tp" dst-port=1701 protocol=udp
add chain=input comment="allow sstp" dst-port=443 protocol=tcp
add chain=input comment="web access for config" dst-port=80 in-interface=ether1-gateway log=yes log-prefix=remote-access protocol=tcp
add action=drop chain=input comment="default configuration" in-interface=ether1-gateway
/ip firewall nat
add action=masquerade chain=srcnat comment="default configuration" out-interface=ether1-gateway to-addresses=0.0.0.0

# may/31/2016 23:03:52 by RouterOS 6.35.1
# software id = 8RIQ-2NZU
#
/ppp profile
add local-address=pptp-pool name=pptp-profile remote-address=pptp-pool
set *FFFFFFFE dns-server=0.0.0.0 use-compression=yes
/ppp secret
add name=USERNAME password=PASSWORD profile=pptp-profile service=pptp
```

### From the logs

```
20:20:35 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto TCP (ACK), 82.132.216.62:14320->82.XXX.XXX.177:1723, len 52
20:20:35 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto TCP (ACK,PSH), 82.132.216.62:14320->82.XXX.XXX.177:1723, len 220
20:20:35 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto TCP (ACK), 82.132.216.62:14320->82.XXX.XXX.177:1723, len 52
20:20:35 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto TCP (ACK,PSH), 82.132.216.62:14320->82.XXX.XXX.177:1723, len 76
20:20:35 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto 47, 82.132.216.62->82.XXX.XXX.177, len 60
20:20:36 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto TCP (ACK), 82.132.216.62:14320->82.XXX.XXX.177:1723, len 52
20:20:36 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto 47, 82.132.216.62->82.XXX.XXX.177, len 59
20:20:36 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto 47, 82.132.216.62->82.XXX.XXX.177, len 50
20:20:36 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto 47, 82.132.216.62->82.XXX.XXX.177, len 48
20:20:36 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto 47, 82.132.216.62->82.XXX.XXX.177, len 98
20:20:36 pptp,ppp,info,account USERNAME logged in, 192.168.200.10
20:20:36 pptp,ppp,info <pptp-USERNAME>: authenticated
20:20:36 pptp,ppp,info <pptp-USERNAME>: terminating...
20:20:36 pptp,ppp,info,account USERNAME logged out, 1 18 28 3 4
20:20:36 pptp,ppp,info <pptp-USERNAME>: disconnected
20:20:36 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto 47, 82.132.216.62->82.XXX.XXX.177, len 50
20:20:36 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto 47, 82.132.216.62->82.XXX.XXX.177, len 44
20:20:36 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto 47, 82.132.216.62->82.XXX.XXX.177, len 50
20:20:36 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto 47, 82.132.216.62->82.XXX.XXX.177, len 44
20:20:36 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto 47, 82.132.216.62->82.XXX.XXX.177, len 74
20:20:36 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto TCP (ACK,FIN), 82.132.216.62:14320->82.XXX.XXX.177:1723, len 52
20:20:36 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto TCP (ACK,FIN), 82.132.216.62:14320->82.XXX.XXX.177:1723, len 52
20:20:36 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto TCP (ACK), 82.132.216.62:14320->82.XXX.XXX.177:1723, len 52
20:20:41 system,info PPTP Server settings changed by admin
20:20:41 system,info PPTP Server settings changed by admin
20:20:43 pptp,info TCP connection established from 82.132.216.62
20:20:43 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto TCP (SYN), 82.132.216.62:14321->82.XXX.XXX.177:1723, len 64
20:20:43 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto TCP (ACK), 82.132.216.62:14321->82.XXX.XXX.177:1723, len 52
20:20:43 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto TCP (ACK,PSH), 82.132.216.62:14321->82.XXX.XXX.177:1723, len 208
20:20:43 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto TCP (ACK), 82.132.216.62:14321->82.XXX.XXX.177:1723, len 52
20:20:43 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto TCP (ACK,PSH), 82.132.216.62:14321->82.XXX.XXX.177:1723, len 220
20:20:43 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto TCP (ACK), 82.132.216.62:14321->82.XXX.XXX.177:1723, len 52
20:20:43 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto TCP (ACK,PSH), 82.132.216.62:14321->82.XXX.XXX.177:1723, len 76
20:20:43 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto 47, 82.132.216.62->82.XXX.XXX.177, len 60
20:20:44 pptp,ppp,info,account USERNAME logged in, 192.168.200.10
20:20:44 pptp,ppp,info <pptp-USERNAME>: authenticated
20:20:44 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto TCP (ACK), 82.132.216.62:14321->82.XXX.XXX.177:1723, len 52
20:20:44 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto 47, 82.132.216.62->82.XXX.XXX.177, len 59
20:20:44 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto 47, 82.132.216.62->82.XXX.XXX.177, len 50
20:20:44 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto 47, 82.132.216.62->82.XXX.XXX.177, len 48
20:20:44 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto 47, 82.132.216.62->82.XXX.XXX.177, len 98
20:20:44 pptp,ppp,info <pptp-USERNAME>: using encoding - MPPE128 stateless
20:20:44 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto 47, 82.132.216.62->82.XXX.XXX.177, len 50
20:20:44 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto 47, 82.132.216.62->82.XXX.XXX.177, len 44
20:20:44 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto 47, 82.132.216.62->82.XXX.XXX.177, len 50
20:20:44 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto 47, 82.132.216.62->82.XXX.XXX.177, len 50
20:20:44 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto 47, 82.132.216.62->82.XXX.XXX.177, len 50
20:20:44 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto 47, 82.132.216.62->82.XXX.XXX.177, len 62
20:20:44 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto 47, 82.132.216.62->82.XXX.XXX.177, len 54
20:20:44 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto 47, 82.132.216.62->82.XXX.XXX.177, len 56
20:20:44 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto 47, 82.132.216.62->82.XXX.XXX.177, len 62
20:20:45 pptp,ppp,info <pptp-USERNAME>: connected
20:20:45 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto 47, 82.132.216.62->82.XXX.XXX.177, len 50
20:20:45 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto 47, 82.132.216.62->82.XXX.XXX.177, len 334
20:20:48 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto 47, 82.132.216.62->82.XXX.XXX.177, len 334
20:20:51 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto 47, 82.132.216.62->82.XXX.XXX.177, len 334
20:20:54 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto 47, 82.132.216.62->82.XXX.XXX.177, len 334
20:20:57 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto 47, 82.132.216.62->82.XXX.XXX.177, len 334
20:21:04 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto 47, 82.132.216.62->82.XXX.XXX.177, len 48
20:21:04 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto TCP (ACK), 82.132.216.62:14321->82.XXX.XXX.177:1723, len 40
20:21:24 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto 47, 82.132.216.62->82.XXX.XXX.177, len 48
20:21:25 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto TCP (ACK), 82.132.216.62:14321->82.XXX.XXX.177:1723, len 40
20:21:44 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto 47, 82.132.216.62->82.XXX.XXX.177, len 48
20:21:45 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto TCP (ACK), 82.132.216.62:14321->82.XXX.XXX.177:1723, len 40
20:22:04 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto 47, 82.132.216.62->82.XXX.XXX.177, len 48
20:22:06 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto TCP (ACK), 82.132.216.62:14321->82.XXX.XXX.177:1723, len 40
20:22:24 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto 47, 82.132.216.62->82.XXX.XXX.177, len 48
20:22:27 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto TCP (ACK), 82.132.216.62:14321->82.XXX.XXX.177:1723, len 40
20:22:32 pptp,ppp,info <pptp-USERNAME>: terminating...
20:22:32 pptp,ppp,info,account USERNAME logged out, 109 1568 98 14 8
20:22:32 pptp,ppp,info <pptp-USERNAME>: disconnected
20:22:32 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto 47, 82.132.216.62->82.XXX.XXX.177, len 57
20:22:32 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto 47, 82.132.216.62->82.XXX.XXX.177, len 57
20:22:32 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto TCP (ACK,FIN), 82.132.216.62:14321->82.XXX.XXX.177:1723, len 52
20:22:32 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto TCP (ACK,FIN), 82.132.216.62:14321->82.XXX.XXX.177:1723, len 52
20:22:32 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto TCP (ACK), 82.132.216.62:14321->82.XXX.XXX.177:1723, len 52
22:00:44 firewall,info remote-access input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto TCP (SYN), 93.174.93.94:47264->82.XXX.XXX.177:80, len 40
22:01:09 firewall,info remote-access input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto TCP (SYN), 61.240.144.64:48406->82.XXX.XXX.177:80, len 40
22:09:42 firewall,info remote-access input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto TCP (ACK), 94.102.49.54:22->82.XXX.XXX.177:80, len 40
22:57:26 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto TCP (SYN), 123.151.149.222:22200->82.XXX.XXX.177:1723, len 40
22:57:26 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto TCP (RST), 123.151.149.222:22200->82.XXX.XXX.177:1723, len 40
22:57:26 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto TCP (RST), 123.151.149.222:22200->82.XXX.XXX.177:1723, len 40
22:57:26 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto TCP (SYN), 123.151.42.61:17122->82.XXX.XXX.177:1723, len 48
22:57:27 pptp,info TCP connection established from 123.151.42.61
22:57:27 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto TCP (ACK), 123.151.42.61:17122->82.XXX.XXX.177:1723, len 40
22:57:27 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto TCP (ACK,PSH), 123.151.42.61:17122->82.XXX.XXX.177:1723, len 196
22:57:27 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto TCP (ACK), 123.151.42.61:17122->82.XXX.XXX.177:1723, len 40
22:57:27 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto TCP (ACK,FIN), 123.151.42.61:17122->82.XXX.XXX.177:1723, len 40
22:57:27 firewall,info input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto TCP (ACK), 123.151.42.61:17122->82.XXX.XXX.177:1723, len 40
22:59:34 firewall,info remote-access input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto TCP (SYN), 141.212.122.151:47113->82.XXX.XXX.177:80, len 40
22:59:34 firewall,info remote-access input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto TCP (SYN), 141.212.122.152:38568->82.XXX.XXX.177:80, len 40
22:59:35 firewall,info remote-access input: in:ether1-gateway out:(none), src-mac 00:01:5c:82:ee:47, proto TCP (SYN), 141.212.122.145:45406->82.XXX.XXX.177:80, len 60
```

I have also enabled proxy-arp on the LAN connections.

I don't know why I cant get traffic to route from VPN > LAN.

Comment: You will need to provide a lot more information. At a very minimum, the device model and configuration the tunnel terminates on, but any relevant information would be useful. As your question stands, we would simply be providing opinion-based answers, and those are off-topic here.

Comment: OK, I can update with more info - is there any specifics you would require I can dump from the box?

Comment: You should include anything that helps in troubleshooting, e.g. logs, and anything else you have done to troubleshoot the problem. If you don't, you will probabl be asked to do things and provide information you already have.

Comment: Is it mandatory to use an IP pool for client and server addresses ? It would be much simplier to use static IPs to route networks.

Comment: @BenoitPHILIPPON I've used an IP Pool for two reasons. 1 - It was in the instructions, 2 - I want more than one connection available (laptop / iphone / ipad) so don't want to assign ip based on user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this I now have it working.

It appears that you need to have on the ppp Secret , the internal local address of the microtik, and then you can either give a static IP for that profile, or assign it one from the DHCP pool you use for your local network.

Then make sure the proxy-arp is on.

So an example for my setup:

Local network = 192.168.88.0/24

Secret:
User = USERNAME
password = PASSWORD
local address = 192.168.88.1
remote address = 192.168.88.10 (OR DHCP POOL)

Answer (score 0):

You can select "proxy-arp" on LAN interface to see another computer in the same subnet. For details, you can watch "How to configure VPN Server on Mikrotik" https://www.youtube.com/edit?video_referrer=watch&video_id=RpJsLMs4AKk